# How to remove the background of jquery tabs without affecting the datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-tabs

I have a jquery tab in my asp.net mvc2 web page, and it has a background(tab content background) that I need to make white. So this is what I typed:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
$(".ui-widget-content").css("background", "none");
});
```

But, this makes my datetime picker also background: none.

I want to do this for the tab content background only. Any ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
$(".ui-widget-content").css("background", "none");
```

Should be:

```
$(".ui-tabs-panel").css("background", "none");
```

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter. The reason for this is because ui-widget-content controls the content section for numerous sections through the page, where as the ui-tabs-panel targets specifically the tabs. Enjoy.